# Simple route with Zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, href, routes

I'm looking for something that is simple but I don't know how to do it after many search. I look at the documentation of Zend 1.12 Route but I don't really understand.

I have these page in the Zend Framework : application/views/scripts/index/
index.phtml
contact.phtml

In the application/views/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml

I want to href to contac.phtml for example. I'm looking for something to do like :

```
$this->url('contact')
```

Then, it redirect to the page contact... But I tried to add an route in the bootstrap.php but I don't really know how...

```
$router->addRoute('contact',
              new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('application/scripts/index/contact.phtml'));
```

Thank you,

David

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the simple codes for routing in zend framework:

- on index.php you should not touch anything. Leave it as it is from Zend default when you create a project
- on projectHomeDirectory/application/Bootstrap.php include this:

  ```
  protected function _initRoutes()
  {
      $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
      include APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/routes.php";
  }
  ```
- create a routes.php file under projectHomeDirectory/application/configs/ and add there all the routes you want, for example:

  ```
  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
      'author',
      array(
          'controller' => 'user',
          'action'     => 'index'
      ) 
  );

  $router->addRoute('author', $route);
  ```

Of course you then need to create the UserController the User model the sample module and the views.

Useful link:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

Answer (score 0):

I use the router resource plugin, I find it convenient to add the routes to my config files (for example the application.ini).

You can find an example and more documentation on the ZF website:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.router

Good luck building your ZF application!