# Zend: Where do you instantiate router object?

Tags: php, zend-framework

The Zend [documentation provides examples](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html) of how to create a route. But it does not say where in the code this example code is applicable. I'm not sure if this goes in a view, controller, or route file in of itself. Zend documentation seems really bad at explaining where everything goes; it rarely marks what code goes into what file. In what file should I instantiate the following route object in Zend?

```
// Create a router

$router = $ctrl->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default
$router->addRoute(
    'user',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('user/:username',
                                     array('controller' => 'user',
                                           'action' => 'info'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd stick it in your Bootstrap.php, like so:

```
protected function _initRoutes() {
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute(
    'user',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('user/:username',
                                 array('controller' => 'user',
                                       'action' => 'info'))
        );
    }
}
```

Or even better,

```
protected function _initRoutes() {
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.php';
}
```

And just put all your routes in the new file. Makes things a bit tidier.

Answer (score 0):

I put all my routes inside

```
protected function _initRoutes(){

}
```

on `Bootstrap.php`. Try

```
protected function _initRoutes(){
     $router = $this->getFront()->getRouter();

     $router->addRoute(
     'user',
     new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('user/:username',
                                 array('controller' => 'user',
                                       'action' => 'info'))
     );
}
```

You can find helpful info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556182/simple-route-with-zend-framework-1-12).